# How to give the on-chip RTC a power backup in Raspberry Pi Pico?

Tags: pi-pico, rtc

I need a power backup for the on-chip RTC on the Raspberry Pi Pico, like a button cell which is quite common. Someone suggested placing a 1.5V button cell between the VSYS pin and the ground. Would that work? Would other components drain the battery as well?

Comment: Welcome. I don't have a pico and will leave the authoritative answer to someone else, but a quick look around implies to me it is 1) An integral part of the RP2040; 2) Does not quite meet everyone's definition of "real time clock" except in so far as it can be used as one programmatically.  A [user here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=325598) says, *"it resets on reboot, can't be tuned and doesn't accept external battery power".*  Also worth noting that several reputable third parties do sell (more normative) RTCs specifically for the pico, that can be battery powered.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks . Going through the link, it seems that there is no option to add an external power source to the on-chip RTC(or rather the on-chip lifetime timer). I have an external RTC module, however, it would have been much more convenient to use the on-chip one.